# Can't find input element by xpath

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, automated-tests

I am trying to get an input element by xpath but the return statement is false.

When I try to get the label, which is the only sibling of the input, it returns true. I have also tried to get it by type input[@type="checkbox"] but it fails too.

```
try {
    var select2 = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//div[@class="arcHier arcVert arcTree"]/ol/li/ul/li[3]/div[@class="dragNode"]/label')))

    WDS.log.info('select2 found')

    var select3 = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//div[@class="arcHier arcVert arcTree"]/ol/li/ul/li[3]/div[@class="dragNode"]/input')))

    WDS.log.info('select3 found')
}
catch (err) {
     WDS.log.error('item not found')
}
```

HTML structure:

```
<li id="4_2_1_292719_8381e915e3af18b6f1f672da1ee582ef_LI" style="line-height:19px;border-color:#a0a0a0;color:#000000;" class="LI_1_2">
    <label class="arcSelectable" style="height:19px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="4_2_1_292719_8381e915e3af18b6f1f672da1ee582ef_X" class="arcHpCbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="arcMenuCheckbox"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="dragNode">
        <input type="checkbox" id="4_2_1_292719_8381e915e3af18b6f1f672da1ee582ef" style="margin-top:3px;">
        <label draggable="false" for="4_2_1_292719_8381e915e3af18b6f1f672da1ee582ef" style="height:19px;">
            <span class="SPAN_1_2" style=""></span>
0001 Training_Test_Company
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
```

The logs file:

1. 2019-07-10 10:55:33,187 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: select2
   found
2. 2019-07-10 10:55:43,310 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: item not
   found

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Can you check in dev tool how many entries are present for input node.

Comment: @cruisepandey there are 116 input elements

Comment: I guess we would need more HTML code to find the xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element may be a hidden checkbox. You can try with `presenceOfElementLocated` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated` as given below.

```
try {
    var select2 = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//div[@class="arcHier arcVert arcTree"]/ol/li/ul/li[3]/div[@class="dragNode"]/label')))

    WDS.log.info('select2 found')

    var select3 = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//div[@class="arcHier arcVert arcTree"]/ol/li/ul/li[3]/div[@class="dragNode"]/input')))

    WDS.log.info('select3 found')
}
catch (err) {
     WDS.log.error('item not found')
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this is possible because the element isn't hidden but it solved the problem. Thank you man, you saved me a lot of time. Best of luck to you.

Comment: those divs have different classes, so if you look at the css you might see the visibility option... "dragNode"